# How to connect PowerShell with CRM online?

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am writing a PowerShell script where it needs to be connected to CRM online.

I can connect to CRM using `Connect-CrmOnline` where it asks for credentials using a login box. I want to automate it. Please guide on how to do it.

Is there a way to connect using connection string? Please share sample code/ script. I am new to PowerShell.

I am using `Microsoft.Xrm.Data.PowerShell`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a credentials object and use that in the script. For example:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "PlainTextPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)
```

You would then use it within your script with `-credential $mycreds` parameter

Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/xrm-tooling/use-powershell-cmdlets-xrm-tooling-connect